# Marketing Cloud domain Delegation

Tags: marketing-cloud, configuration

I have a one question regarding delegation sub domain in marketing cloud

I'm confusing that how to set-up dns and domain.

from what i saw quickstart Documentation that have a lot of way for Subdomain and DNS setting. So, I Tryed to no.3 option that is "Delegate a domain or subdomain you own INTERMEDIATE" and I explain to our client but they are cannot understand this example.

Our client have managing DNS and Domain on Windows Server. also, they haveMain Domain and IP Address. So, I requested them to create new Subdomain. but they don't know which ip address to use.

anybody tell me how to set-up Subdomain and IP Address on Windows Server DNS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is really unclear, but let me try answering it anyway - given example.com being the domain of your client:

Create a subdomain, e.g. marketing.example.com

Delegate this subdomain to name servers of Salesforce, by creating following NS records on clients's DNS server, for example.com domain:

```
marketing                         IN NS               ns1.exacttarget.com
marketing                         IN NS               ns2.exacttarget.com
marketing                         IN NS               ns3.exacttarget.com
marketing                         IN NS               ns4.exacttarget.com
```

In this case, you don't have to worry about the IP address or anything. Salesforce will take care of creating all the needed A, CNAME, TXT and MX records for the solution to work.

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve the unclear problem.
i'm finally starting to figure out the problem. really Thanks again.